# how to call paintComponent when button is clicked JavaJDK NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to call paintComponent  class just if button is clicked that's using JavaJDK Gui NetBeans

```
public class KnnJDK extends Application {

    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     Button butt = new Button();
        butt.setText("Applique KPPV");
        grid.add(butt, 0, 5);
     butt.setOnAction(event -> {
         // i want to call it here !

     });
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
         // dessiner les points 
        for (int i =0;i<n;i++)
        {
            g.fillOval(ListX[i], ListY[i], 20, 20);
        }       
        //dessiner les arcs
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
            for (int j =0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if ((mAdjG[i][j]==1)&&(i!=j)){
                    g.drawLine(ListX [i]+10, ListY [i]+10, ListX [j]+10, ListY [j]+10);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

How to do that ?
thanks for reading and helping

Answer (score 0):

just remove this package import javafx.scene.control.Button;

```
   package knnjdkwithdgr;


  import java.awt.*; 

  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Collections;


 public class KnnJDKWithDGR extends Application implements ActionListener{




    public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
  int n = 10;
  int ListX []=new int[n];
  int ListY []=new int[n];
 // dessiner les points 
    for (int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        g.fillOval(ListX[i], ListY[i], 20, 20);
    }        
}



@Override

public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{

    Button buttdgr = new Button();

    buttdgr.addActionListener(this);


 }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

  }

   }
```

Comment: there is an error here `buttdgr.setActionListener(new ActionListener()` exacte in `setActionListener ` , how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you imported required packages

Comment: `error: cannot find symbol
        buttdgr.setActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  symbol:   method setActionListener(<anonymous ActionListener>)
  location: variable buttdgr of type Button
1 error  `

Comment: what packages shoud i import ?

Comment: Import Java.awt.*; import java.awt.event.*;

Comment: Did you import java.awt.event.ActionListener;?

Comment: send me your import statements

Comment: Try removing this import javafx.scene.control.Button;

Comment: I am extremely sorry that is addActionListener

Comment: Did you get it ?

Comment: sorry, i have the same error :( error: cannot find symbol
        buttdgr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  symbol:   method addActionListener(<anonymous ActionListener>)

Comment: i think there is problem in my NetBeans, thats the full JavaJDK code `https://pastebin.com/nMeTdJ0W` try it if u dont mind

Comment: This site says user removed content send the code I'll try